# Javascript "this" scope

Tags: javascript

I am writing some JavaScript code. I am a little confused about this keyword. How do I access logger variable in the `dataReceivedHandler` function?

```
MyClass: {
    logger: null,
    init: function() {
        logger = LogFactory.getLogger();
    },
    loadData: function() {
        var dataReceivedHandler = function() {
            // how to access the logger variable here? 
        }

        // more stuff
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `loadData` is called like so:

```
MyClass.loadData();
```

then:

```
loadData: function() {
    var self = this;
    var dataReceivedHandler = function() {
        self.logger ...
    }

    // more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like this inside the loadData function to access your object...

```
MyClass: {
    logger: null,
    init: function() {
        this.logger = LogFactory.getLogger();
    },
    loadData: function() {
        var self = this;
        var dataReceivedHandler = function() {
            // how to access the logger variable here? 
            self.logger.log('something');
        }

        // more stuff
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `dataReceivedHandler` is an anonymous function `this` will refer to the window object on the global scope. I think of two way you can bypass that.

a) Create a variable inside `loadData` to hold it's context then use it inside `dataReceivedHandler` as such:

```
loadData: function() {
    var self = this;
    var dataReceivedHandler = function() {
        console.log(self.logger);
    }

    // more stuff
}
```

b) Change the context of your anonymous function using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```
loadData: function() {
    var dataReceivedHandler = function() {
        console.log(this.logger);
    }
    // more stuff
    dataReceivedHandler.call(this); // by passing this as the first argument we make sure the context of the excuted function is our current scope's this
}
```

I prefer option B due to performance and memory usage optimizations, but both would work just fine.

Comment: _"Because dataReceivedHandler is an anonymous function this will refer to the window object on the global scope."_ - It's not anonymous when you refer to it by the name `dataReceivedHandler`. And anonymous or not the value of `this` depends on how the function is _called_, not how it is defined (as you presumably know given your second example). Note that both methods in your answer will only work if `loadData()` is called in a way that sets its `this` to the `MyClass` object.

Comment: When declaring a function without a name which is returned into a variable (`function() {}` instead of `function name() {}`) this is what you call an anonymous function. Anonymous function's context will always be `window` unless overridden by a method such as `call` or `apply`. Am I wrong about that? If so please show an example proving otherwise.

Comment: I'm correcting myself. If an anonymous function is part of an object (namespace), this will refer to the object as long as the method is executed directly from it.

Comment: Although I have not mentioned, in my example dataReceivedHandler will be called upon the completion of ajax request. Is option B still a better choice in that case?

Comment: If you are building a large scale application then it's best to think about these things while writing your code and design it to fit your programming style. In general you can always use option A and if you still wanna optimize you memory usage just unset self after the ajax call was executed. You can do so by using `self = undefined` which will allow the garbage collector to get rid of the data/reference more easily if required.

Comment: Thanks. I shall check this.

Comment: @iMoses—"When declaring a function without a name..." that would be a [function expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13), not a declaration. ;-)

Comment: @bluetech I think this should be the accepted answer, because it is the only one to mention the intended use of the this-keyword and its context dependent scope, i.e. option B.