# State is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using `Flickr api` to make a **Simple Image Carousel** and facing a problem where my state does not get `updated` or `rendered` whenever I click the button.

Here is my **index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import _ from 'lodash';

import Photo from './components/photo';

const urlArr = [];
const apiKey = "API";
const userId = "ID";
const url = `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=${apiKey}&user_id=${userId}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { urlArr: [] };

    axios.get(url)
    .then((photoData) => {
      _.forEach(photoData.data.photos.photo, (photo) => {
        urlArr.push(`https://farm6.staticflickr.com//${photo.server}//${photo.id}_${photo.secret}_z.jpg`);
      });
      this.setState({ urlArr });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Photo urls={this.state.urlArr}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

and here is my **photo.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NextButton from './nextButton';
import PrevButton from './prevButton';

class Photo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { idx: 0 };
    this.nextImg = this.nextImg.bind(this);
  }

  nextImg() {
    this.setState({ idx: this.state.idx++ });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.urls.length === 0) {
      return <div>Image Loading...</div>
    }

    console.log(this.state);
    return(
      <div>
        <PrevButton />
        <img src={this.props.urls[this.state.idx]}/>
        <NextButton onClick={this.nextImg}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Photo;
```

and my **nextButton.js** (same as **prevButton.js**)

```
import React from 'react';

const NextButton = () =>{
  return (
    <div>
      <button>next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NextButton;
```

Since I'm fairly new to *React*, I'm not quite sure why my `this.state.idx` is not getting updated when I click on the *next* button (Seems to me that it is not even firing nextImg function either). If anyone can give me a help or advice, that would really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should check if `nextImg` get fired when you click on the button

Answer (score 1):

Update your NextButton. Use the event within your presentational component.

```
<NextButton next={this.nextImg}/>
```

And the NextButton component should looks like this.

```
import React from 'react';
 const NextButton = (props) =>{
 return (<div>
    <button onClick={props.next}>next</button>
  </div>
 );
};
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work..and I thought this.nextImg = this.nextImg.bind(this) in my constructor is taking care of that..not sure tho..

Comment: it still does not update my state. However, whenever I click 'next', it logs props as an empty object.

Comment: See the above answer, `this.setState({ urlArr });` is not being called in the right context in your main Component constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with this piece of code:

```
axios.get(url)
.then((photoData) => {
  _.forEach(photoData.data.photos.photo, (photo) => {
    urlArr.push(`https://farm6.staticflickr.com//${photo.server}//${photo.id}_${photo.secret}_z.jpg`);
  });
  this.setState({ urlArr });
});
```

`this` refers to the `axios.get` callback scope and not the Component. You can define another variable called `self` or something that makes more sense to you and call `self.setState()`.

See this question for a similar problem: [Javascript "this" scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823948/javascript-this-scope)